# HTML5 and SPA dependence

Tags: html, single-page-application

Have Single page applications become possible owing to HTML5 ,or it is just a coincidence that they both gained prominence at the same time?

If these are interlinked - what are the specific features of HTML5 that made SPA possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with HTML5. There were plenty of SPA in HTML4. SPA came with the rise of JavaScript as client programming language and especially with the ability to do AJAX requests.